# SVG path data format differences

Tags: svg

I'm working on a project where I need to parse svg path data.

Right now we're loading an svg, looking for the `path` tag, and pulling out it's `d` attribute.

For some of the artwork we'll get path data that is made up of coordinates which we can translate into the data types we need. E.g.

[image: the kind of d attribute format we want]

But other times the `d` value is in a more g-code-esq format.

Like in this case I drew a rectangle, converted it to a compound path:

[image: rect illustration]

And when I export it and look at the svg I get a `d` value like this:

[image]

Which we can't easily parse for the project.

My questions are:

- How do I read this second format? It doesn't seem to fit what I'm reading on MDN so I suspect there's some other documentation I need to refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d
- For illustrator users, is there a way of changing the format when exporting?

I know that this seems like more of an art question than a programming question, but I'm trying to understand the underlying reasoning behind the svg data structure so I can better parse it.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands

Comment: Also this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#Path_commands

Comment: The official path format is this: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! Oh ok, I was 100% misunderstanding the path data that I was reading. I didn't realize that the delimiting information was based on the letter. My brain wanted some specific character as a delimiter like a comma or pipe.

So reading (and in some cases re-reading :| ) the documentation, when I see:

```
M753,315H435.27V165H753Z
```

I can read that as:

- `M753,315` Move to x,y coordinates `x: 753 y:315`
- `H435.27` Starting at the current location, draw a horizontal line to the absolute `x` coordinate of `435.27`
- `V165` Starting at the current location, draw a vertical line to the absolute `y` coordinate of `165`
- `H753` Starting at the current location, draw a horizontal line to the absolute `x` coordinate of `753`
- `Z`Draw a straight line to the initial point of this path to close the path. This doesn't necessarily mean a horizontal or vertical line, but the coincidence that we're at the same `x` coordinate that we started at means that if we draw a straight line we will get a vertical line to complete the rectangle

That seems right. Anything I missed or misunderstood?

Also, thank for all of the links. I appreciate the points :clap: :bows: